# Does gmail have elements made in flash?

Tags: gmail

What mix of languages and other elements are used in gmail. HTML, JavaScript, AJAX(?), CSS... what else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe they use flash for the attachment file upload percentage meter from memory...

Comment: And I'm I right in the list above? AJAX?

Comment: @Roger - I would say judging by the way it injects content into the page without performing a page reload that it must.